# Discord.js guild.roles.cache.find returning undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Im trying to assign code a discord bot to give someone a role whenever they enter a server. This is my code right now:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    let role = guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Admin");
    console.log(role);
    if(!role){
      console.log("Role doesen't exist.");
    }
    member.roles.add(role);
});
```

I tried running it, and this line executed: `console.log("Role doesen't exist.");`. I then went on to print the role variable, and it was undefined. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First Method

Everything might not be available in cache, so you need to fetch it, the only issue is that you need to fetch via the ID.

```
let role = guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'ADMIN') || await guild.roles.fetch('ROLEID');
```

Source: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=fetch

## Second Method

This is a rather hacky solution, but you can fetch all roles on ready event.

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach(g => {      
      g.roles.fetch();
});
```

Comment: afaik role caches are populated on start up.

Comment: It is supposed to be populated on startup, but there are situations where it is not cached.

Comment: @AlhassanRaad then how do I cache it?

Comment: @Serket using [`RoleManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=fetch)

Comment: How do I find the roleid?

Comment: I posted another method which you can do if you can't get the roleid